# How to target a specific day in sort?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I show the word TESTING for `Date.current` in the proper order of the list?

```
<% @lifetime_years.sort.each do |year, lifetimes| %>
  <%= year.strftime('%Y') %>
  <% lifetimes.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_month }.sort.each do |month, lifetimes| %>
    <%= month.strftime('%B') %>
    <% for lifetime in lifetimes %>
      <%= lifetime.deadline %>: <%= lifetime.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For example,

```
2016
  January
    18: Run a Marathon (aka lifetime object)
    25: Eat a piece of poop (aka lifetime object)
  February
    1: Resolve SO Question (aka lifetime object)
    1: TESTING
  March
    5: Write a Book (aka lifetime object)
```

In other words, how can I target a specific day within sort so that I can add additional information unrelated to `lifetime`?

### UPDATE

```
<% @lifetime_years.sort.each do |year, lifetimes| %>
  <%= year.strftime('%Y') %>
  <% lifetimes.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_month }.sort.each do |month, lifetime| %>
    <%= month.strftime('%B') %>
    <% for lifetime in lifetimes %>
      <%= lifetime.deadline %>: <%= lifetime.name %>
    <% end %>

#CHANGED THIS PARAGRAPH
<% @routines.each do |routine| %>
  <% if lifetime.deadline == Date.current %>
    <p><%= routine.action %></p>
  <% else %>
    NONE
  <% end %>
<% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This correctly lists the `routines` on the current day, BUT only if there is a `lifetime` with a `deadline` present. Is there a way we can list all the `routines` for the current day even if no `lifetime` exists?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you writing a test of some sort? Or are you trying to override something for manual testing?

Comment: I'm trying to use another object called, `routine` to show all the routines a user has under `Date.current`. So that would take the place of TESTING for my purposes @Jon

Comment: Hmm. This is still confusing. You have some sample data - does it cover the case you're worried about? (if not, please change it so it does) - can you add the output you're looking for given that sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to. Just inject an `if` block in your ERB:

```
<% @lifetime_years.sort.each do |year, lifetimes| %>
  <%= year.strftime('%Y') %>
  <% lifetimes.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_month }.sort.each do |month, lifetime| %>
    <%= month.strftime('%B') %>
    <% for lifetime in lifetimes %>
      <%= lifetime.deadline %>: <%= lifetime.name %>
    <% end %>

    <% if lifetime == Date.current %>
      <%= "Some extra information from Ruby code" %>
      <p>Some extra plaintext</p>
    <% else %>
      <%= [lifetime, Date.current] %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but "Some extra plaintext" didn't show up anywhere. Good try though.

Comment: My ERB is definitely not up to snuff, I do everything in HAML or Slim. That said, I bet the conditional isn't triggering, rather than the ERB being incorrect. What's the complete condition you want to check against?

Comment: Added an "else" condition that may help you to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Sorry Narf that didn't work either. But your advice helped get me closer. I updated the question with the progress we made :)